# Replace a specific value of a key in dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary

Am having troubles with replacing a certain value for a key in dictionary.

```
dictionary = {'accesskey': 4567, 'name': u'D:\\PROG'}
```

Am trying to replace the value for `'name'` when name has `'\'` in it, with `'other'`.

Appreciate any little help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Ok, but what's the problem? Do you know how to access keys in a dict? Do you know how to check if a string contains a backslash? Do you know how to assign values to a dict?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to simply replace the value of `'name'` with `'other'`:

```
dictionary['name'] = 'other'
```

If you would like to replace the value of `'name'` with `'other'` if the value of `'name'` contains `'\\'`:

```
if '\\' in dictionary['name']:
    dictionary['name'] = 'other'
```

If you would like to search all dictionary values for one that contains `'\\'`, and then replace that value with `'other'`:

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    if '\\' in str(v):
        dictionary[k] = 'other'
```

`v` is cast to a string to make it iterable.

Hope this helps.